# fastapi 'Depends' object has no attribute 'execute'

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, fastapi

I was trying to call an asynchronous function inside my async route function, I got this error  `the exception is  'Depends' object has no attribute 'execute'`, the line that causes the error was `company_specialization = await getCompanySpecialization()` I wonder why I can not do this?!!

This is a part of the code

#### routers/company

```py
@router.get('/Company/{id}')
async def getCompanyItem(id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_async_session)):
    try:
        query = select(Company).where(Company.id == id)
        results = await db.execute(query)
        data = results.scalars().first()
        if not data:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=404,
                detail="Utilisateur non trouvé"
            )
        else:
            company_specialization = await getCompanySpecialization()
            return {
                "success": "True",
                'data': data
            }
    except Exception as e:
        print("the exception is ", e)
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=500,
            detail=f'Une erreur est survenue, veuillez réessayer ultérieurement.'
        )
```

#### controllers/company

```py
async def getCompanySpecialization():
    return {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "ok"
    }
```

Comment: I do not think so cause once I remove the line I mentioned above everything is ok

Comment: Are you sure that that is the actual definition of the `getCompanySpecialization` method you're using? The point is that if `getCompanySpecialization` has a `Depends` argument, and you're calling it manually, it will not be resolved as you assume. You'd have to either pass in the dependency manually or create a dependency hierarchy where a service with the relevant configuration is set up in another `Depends` in the function signature. FastAPI does not resolve `Depends` at random locations in your code, only as part of an existing Depends hierarchy from the view function or other Dependencies